# How can I set mtime with sub-second precision?

Tags: linux, files, scripting

I have a bunch of photographs I copied from OS X to a Samba mount on a Linux system using `cp -a`. For some reason, the mtimes of the target files got set to the current time rather than the mtime of the source files. I tried to remedy this by copying the files using Finder instead, and now the mtimes were apparently copied over, but only at 1 second precision, which mixes up the time order of the files when using e.g. `ls -ltr` to view them.

I can see higher-precision mtimes on the original files. How can I set the mtimes on the target files with higher precision? `touch -m -t $timestamp` only seems to support 1 second precision.

Comment: What filesystems are involved on the macOS and on the Linux sides? There are filesystems that simply can't store timestamps more precisely than to a 1 or 2 second precision. See also [How can I get high-precision timestamps (better than 1s) with Samba?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/55567)

Comment: AFAIK, ext3 does not support sub-second timestamps; ext4 and XFS do.

Comment: On the Mac side it's either HFS+ or APFS. Regardless, the accurate timestamps are present there, as can be seen with e.g. stat. The network protocol is some version of SMB that the Mac and Linux managed to negotiate, and on Linux side it's ext4.

Answer (score -1):

Since you copied the files, I recommend you to use `touch`:

```
touch -r ref-file target-file
```

If the reason for copying the files via SMB is missing local disk space for a `tar` archive with all the file content, there is a way to copy just the meta data which includes time stamps using `star`:

```
star -c -dump -meta . > /tmp/meta.tar
```

creates a `tar` archive with sub second granularity that only contains the files meta data.

Now copy that `tar` archive to the other side and extract only the meta data, leaving the file content as is:

```
star -x -meta < /tmp/meta.tar
```

Note that you need the `-U` option ad well, if you are using an outdated version of `star` since before May 2018 `star` did not compare the sub second part when deciding whether a file in the archive is newer than on disk.

Comment: The trouble here is that the files are shared to Mac using SMB, which only supports 1 second precision in timestamps. That is, I don't have the files with accurate timestamps on the target system, and copying them there reduces timestamp precision.

Comment: I added a `star` based solution that should work for you.

Comment: I presume `star` here is https://sourceforge.net/projects/s-tar/.

Comment: I recommend to fetch `schilytools` as this gets frequent updates and contains version 1.6.1 already while the stand-alone archive is at release 1.6.